# Upgrading to Java 7u65 breaks my Deployment Rule Set for Oracle applications

Tags: oracle, xml, java

My company uses an older version of an Oracle application that requires Java 6u45. Naturally we want to be secure, so we use a Deployment Rule Set to specify 6u45 for that internal application and let other applications use 7u60. Now that we're ready to upgrade the Java 7 half to 7u67, the Oracle application breaks with "Deployment Rule Set required version 1.6.0_45 not available." Of course it is available, it just can't find it for some reason. As a test, I specified that JavaTester.org should use 6u45 also and it works fine with no issues. But when I try to use the same configuration (7u67 and 6u45) against the Oracle application it fails every time. If I downgrade to 7u60, it works. 7u65 or higher, it breaks. The Oracle application hasn't changed so it must be something different in how 7u65+ is handling Deployment Rule Sets or pathing or something. I'm at a complete loss.

ruleset.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 -<ruleset version="1.0+">
  -<rule>
   <id location="*.mycorp.com"/>
    <action version="1.6.0_45" permission="run"/>
  </rule>
  -<rule>
   <id location="http://javatester.org"/>
    <action version="1.6.0_45" permission="run"/>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: It turns out that it had nothing to do with the rule set. Our version of Oracle is using 6u16 and apparently the update to 7u65 or 7u67 doesn't work properly if 6u45 is installed. Rather than downgrade everyone to 6u16 we're simply spoofing it by using deployment.properties to say "Java 6u16 you're located here: jre6" which is the location of 6u45. Then we updated the rule set to look for 6u16. It seems to work though I think the permanent solution is an Oracle upgrade.